# how to use union query on the same table and different group by in mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-by, union

I have sql query like this:

```
select a.x, a.y, sum(a.foo) as foo_sum
from a
group by a.x
```

and after running this query, I can access to foo_sum.

I want to do something like this:

```
select a.x, a.y, sum(a.foo) as foo_sum
from a
group by a.x
union
select a.x, a.y, sum(a.bar) as bar_sum
from a
group by a.y
```

but after running this one, my program dosent know foo_sum, anybody knows why?

thank you.

**Edit**: I want to have 4 column x, y, foo_sum and bar_sum, is this possible?

Comment: quick question - you know database table names are case-sensitive, right? i.e. if your table is called `A` you can't reference its columns with `a.x`, you have to use `A.x`. In fact, that may be your problem.

Comment: actually its not 'A', the correct is 'a'! I'll correct this, thanks.

Comment: Hmm, if I create a table `a` with columns `x`,`y`,`foo` and `bar` and run your query on them, it works - I get a column with three columns, `x`, `y` and `foo_sum`, with the rows from both queries (the `bar_sum` rows appear on the `foo_sum` column). What exact error are you experiencing? ("My program doesn't know foo_sum" -- does the query work when you type it directly into the mysql client? If so, we can narrow down the problem to your program).

Comment: "the bar_sum rows appear on the foo_sum column" this is my problem, I want to have 4 column x, y, foo_sum and bar_sum, is this possible?

Comment: ahh, now I see what you mean. You should put that in your question when you ask because it isn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, because your number of unique `x` values might not be the same as the number of unique `y` values.

For example, suppose `a` was like this:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| x    | y    | foo  | bar  |
+------+------+------+------+
|    1 |    1 |    3 |    4 |
|    1 |    2 |    3 |    6 |
|    1 |    1 |    3 |    6 |
|    1 |    2 |    8 |    3 |
|    2 |    1 |    7 |   32 |
|    2 |    2 |    7 |   34 |
|    2 |    3 |    8 |    3 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

The first query (`foo_sum GROUP BY x`) would give:

```
+------+------+---------+
| x    | y    | foo_sum |
+------+------+---------+
|    1 |    1 |      17 |
|    2 |    1 |      22 |
+------+------+---------+
```

The second (`bar_sum GROUP BY y`) gives:

```
+------+------+---------+
| x    | y    | bar_sum |
+------+------+---------+
|    1 |    1 |      42 |
|    1 |    2 |      43 |
|    2 |    3 |       3 |
+------+------+---------+
```

How can you mash the `bar_sum` column on the end of the `foo_sum` table? There is *no* corresponding `foo_sum` value for (x,y)=(2,3), but there *is* a corresponding `bar_sum`.

The best you could achieve would be something like this:

```
+------+------+---------+-------+
| x    | y    | bar_sum |foo_sum|
+------+------+---------+-------+
|    1 |    1 |      42 |    17 |
|    1 |    2 |      43 |  NULL |
|    2 |    3 |       3 |  NULL |
|    2 |    1 |    NULL |    22 |
+------+------+---------+-------+
```

To achieve this the only way I can think of is using a `FULL OUTER JOIN`. Note that doing `SELECT x, y, SUM(foo), SUM(bar) FROM a GROUP BY x,y` won't give the same results as it groups differently.

```
SELECT t1.x,t1.y,foo_sum,bar_sum
FROM
(SELECT x, y, SUM(foo) as foo_sum
FROM A
GROUP BY x) t1
FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT x, y, SUM(bar) as bar_sum
FROM A
GROUP BY y) t2
ON t1.x=t2.x AND t1.y=t2.y
```

This makes sure all the `x,y` combinations from each table is inserted, even if there are no corresponding `x,y` in the other table.

**However** MySQL has no `FULL OUTER JOIN`, and you have to simulate a `A FULL OUTER JOIN B` by `UNION`ing a `LEFT` and `RIGHT` join together:

```
SELECT ...
 FROM A LEFT JOIN B ON ...
UNION
SELECT ...
 FROM A RIGHT JOIN B ON ...
```

In your case this translates to the very ugly:

```
SELECT t1.x,t1.y,foo_sum,bar_sum
FROM
(SELECT x, y, SUM(foo) as foo_sum
FROM A
GROUP BY x) t1
LEFT JOIN                        -- need FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT x, y, SUM(bar) as bar_sum
FROM A
GROUP BY y) t2
ON t1.x=t2.x AND t1.y=t2.y

UNION

SELECT t2.x,t2.y,foo_sum,bar_sum
FROM
(SELECT x, y, SUM(foo) as foo_sum
FROM A
GROUP BY x) t1
RIGHT JOIN                        -- need FULL OUTER JOIN
(SELECT x, y, SUM(bar) as bar_sum
FROM A
GROUP BY y) t2
ON t1.x=t2.x AND t1.y=t2.y
```

This is *highly inefficient* ! I suggest you instead do the grouping on the PHP side (or whatever other language you are using with MySQL) than the SQL side.

Who knows, there may be a more efficient way to do this since all you want is `SUM`s - there could be a clever way to group and sum to achieve your effect.

Comment: thank you very much, I think you are right, in this case, the php side is more efficient than the sql side!

Answer (score 0):

Is this same as:

```
select a.x, a.y, sum(a.foo) as foo_sum, sum(a.bar) as bar_sum 
from a 
group by a.x ,a.y
```

Comment: no, it isn't, because this now looks at *unique* cominations of x and y before doing the sums.